# Manage different devices on one place

Tags: applications, android-device-manager, gps-tracking, multiple-devices

I would like to manage different Android devices on one place. It means I would like to see information about these devices on a single account. Mainly I would like to get a list of installed applications, latest geographical position.

Comment: And you have already checked with the [relevant Q&As](/questions/tagged/multiple-devices) here on this site – and nothing fits? What about [Which program allows remote management of Android devices?](/q/56857/16575) And are you asking for multiple devices *you* own (and run with a single e.g. Google account) – or about managing all devices of an international corporation (just to name two extremes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do what you're looking for.

One option is to use a parental control app that lets you see the location, browsing history, apps downloads, sms activities, etc.
One such app is called [qustodio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qustodio.qustodioapp). You can find many similar ones online.

Sending method:
This method will require you to have the Google account password for the device in question. (This method is only ideal if all devices are using the same Google account)

- open [play.Google.Com](http://play.Google.com) in your browser in desktop view and after signing in, go to the menu>apps, and you'll see a drop down list. In the list select the device for which you want to see installed apps. Scroll through the list to see the apps that were installed
- to see the location of the device, you can use Google's [find my device](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.google.com/android/find&ved=0ahUKEwjOur3E3dLXAhUn44MKHdc9BD8QFggpMAE&usg=AOvVaw18MrvVnXQpTGzGjml46v_F) option. After logging in you'll see the location of the phone. (Note: sometimes the phone will get a notification that the device was located using this option)